# tabularx: underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in alignment

Tags: tabularx, warnings, badness

I'd like to have table of 15cm with fixed-width cells. I use tabularx package. For some reason, the following code gives **underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in alignment** . What causes this warning? How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[polish]{babel}

\usepackage[top=25mm,bottom=25mm,left=35mm,right=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{tabularx}{150mm}{|>{\hsize=0.3\hsize}X|>{\hsize=0.6\hsize}X|>{\hsize=1\hsize}X|>{\hsize=1.55\hsize}X|>{\hsize=1\hsize}X|>{\hsize=1.55\hsize}X|}
\hline
a & b & c & d & e & f \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fixed-width" cells? As in, you know their lengths?

Comment: That is no problem. There are internal rounding errors. Try `... >{\hsize=1.45\hsize}X|X|>{\hsize=1.65\hsize}X|}
\hline ` and it should go. I used a short `X` for `\hsize=1\hsize`

Comment: Thank you. I knew it has something to do with rounding. So If i use 1.55 then 2.5cm*1.55=3.875 and there are three digits after comma, which causes rounding error. Is it possible to fix this rounding error somehow?

Comment: Hmm... on the other hand, 2.5cm*1.45=3.625 and again three digits after comma, but no error. Perhaps I don't understand why those errors happen.

Answer (score 6):

I really wouldn't use `tabularx` here, as you  really know all the column widths in advance, however if you do use it you can add some stretch glue to pad out the box

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[polish]{babel}

\usepackage[top=25mm,bottom=25mm,left=35mm,right=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{tabularx}{150mm}{!{\extracolsep{\fill}}|>{\hsize=0.3\hsize}X|>{\hsize=0.6\hsize}X|>{\hsize=1\hsize}X|>{\hsize=1.55\hsize}X|>{\hsize=1\hsize}X|>{\hsize=1.55\hsize}X|}
\hline
a & b & c & d & e & f \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\hbox to 150mm{\hbox to 149.99mm{}}


\end{document}
```

The problem is that if a box is a fraction overfull TeX will not report it (if it is less than `\hfuzz`) but an underful box with no stretchable glue is always infinitely bad, as shown by the `\hbox` example at the end of the above.